# PySpark filter: AttributeError: 'numpy.float32' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

In PySpark, I would like to filter a spark dataframe like this

```
 temp_df = df1.filter(df1.latitude_float.between(lat_min, lat_max) & df1.longitude_float.between(lng_min, lng_max))
```

`df1` is a dataframe constructed through `spark.sql`, here are the results of `printSchema`

```
 |-- vin_nbr: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timstm_hm: string (nullable = true)
 |-- latitude: string (nullable = true)
 |-- longitude: string (nullable = true)
 |-- make: string (nullable = true)
 |-- model: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timstm_hm_timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- latitude_float: float (nullable = true)
 |-- longitude_float: float (nullable = true)
```

As you can see, latitude_float and longitude_float are indeed float. `lat_min`,`lat_max`,`lng_min` and `lng_max` are float as well. Why am I getting this error?

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.float32' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Comment: is your lat_min numpy float or python native float?

Comment: @E.ZY. I figured it out. The problem is I was comparing float32 with float64. I make the two the same type, and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seem you are passing numpy types to spark. Print `type(lat_min)`, what does it output? It must be a pure python type `<class 'float'>`

To convert a numpy type to python call its `.item()` methods

```
lat_min.item()
```

Comment: I figured it out. The problem is I was comparing float32 with float64. I make the two the same type, and it works. Thanks.